# Why no young gc happening and the Old capacity remains the same?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have one java application running for some time now. I did a jstat data capture. Here is what I capture some where 24 hours before.

```
Timestamp         S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
      2131522.8   0.00   0.00  18.50 100.00  67.22   3571   44.690   250  246.307  290.997
      2131527.9   0.00   0.00  19.15 100.00  67.22   3571   44.690   250  246.307  290.997
      2131532.9   0.00   0.00  19.80 100.00  67.22   3571   44.690   250  246.307  290.997
      2131537.9   0.00   0.00  20.07 100.00  67.22   3571   44.690   250  246.307  290.997
```

After 24 hours I capture this

```
2303075.6   0.00   0.00  12.66 100.00  67.22   3571   44.690   515  508.618 553.308
2303080.5   0.00   0.00  13.41 100.00  67.22   3571   44.690   515  508.618  553.308
2303085.6   0.00   0.00  14.79 100.00  67.22   3571   44.690   515  508.618  553.308
2303515.7   0.00   0.00 100.00 100.00  67.22   3571   44.690   516  508.618  553.308
2303520.7   0.00   0.00   7.84 100.00  67.22   3571   44.690   516  509.544  554.234
```

Here I would took out some data in between the I just took the start of full GC 515 and full GC of 516.

Here is the gc I capture after 24 hours.

```
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       PC     PU                   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
2816.0 2816.0  0.0    0.0   242752.0 95431.4   497024.0   497024.0  21504.0 1445               5.5   3571   44.690  514   507.139  551.829
2816.0 2816.0  0.0    0.0   242752.0 96806.2   497024.0   497024.0  21504.0 1445               5.5   3571   44.690  514   507.139  551.829
2816.0 2816.0  0.0    0.0   242752.0 98382.0   497024.0   497024.0  21504.0 1445               5.5   3571   44.690  514   507.139  551.829
```

What worries be here is that after 24 hours there is not any YGC its like stucked at 3571. Only FGC is keep happening and the Old capacity if fully used? Does it indicate some issue or problem here?

Comment: What garbage collector and what JDK version do you use?

Comment: I am using jdk 1.7 the oracle version I dont know which garbage vrsion how to determine?

Comment: To find out the GC type run your program with `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` option. It will print all the Java option to stdout. Find `UseG1GC`, `UseParallelGC` and `UseConcMarkSweepGC`. One of these will be set to true. Which one? Also, please, provide the full JDK version, including the build number.

Comment: @AndrewLygin my application is running using the yajsw wrapper. So I had to shut down and run it manually using the java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal  and I find out that both the rest are false except for UseParallelGC. I dont know if running it via the yajsw is using the same type of garbage version? Anyway my java version is Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b04). Currently my appllication I have just restart it. So far it has now started with the YGC but not FGC yet. What is your next suggestion should I increase the memory or leave it first? The initmemory and maxmemory is 728 mb

Comment: Based on this statistics I would say that your current settings definitely don't fit your application demands. But still the absence of young collections looks weird. It seems that your program is always trying to create large objects that don't fit into the young gen. Do you have `NewRatio`, `NewSize` or `MaxNewSize` Java options set?

Comment: I would also try another analysis tool, like `jconsole` or some third party profiler, before jumping to conclusions. There were several issues with correctness of information in `jstat`, and you have pretty outdated JDK version. It might occur that the real statistics differs from what it shows you.

Comment: So what settings do you suggest. Yes is pretty weird the young collection is not working. How to check on the newRatio, newSize or maxNewSize? I am very new to this tuning?

Comment: What options should I put with jconsole and capture it? Yes I know my JDK is pretty old but it has been running this same application on other machines for some years now. I dare not change but this machine will have much more load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120846/discussion-between-user5313398-and-andrew-lygin).

Comment: Do you think I should capture the jmap heap and do some analysis in MAT tool ?

Comment: I answered in the chat